# ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Tags: oracle11g

In oracle 11G, I want to drop a user PERMANENTLY, ie no trace of that user should remain and I should not get "existing object" errors like this - ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object, when I try to recreate that User with its tables.

Please help me to do this.
Thanks.

EDIT -

Commands to create user with table and columns

```
CREATE USER Products identified by discounted
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO Products
CREATE TABLE Cars(Brand varchar(25),Model varchar(25))
```

The above is followed by,
Commands to drop user completely and re-create it completely

```
DROP USER PRODUCTS CASCADE
CREATE USER Products identified by discounted
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO Products
CREATE TABLE Cars(Brand varchar(25),Model varchar(25))
```

Causes the exception-

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

Comment: Is this a very difficult question ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you getting the error when you create the user or when you create the tables?

Comment: @eaolson - I get this error when I try to create a table with columns.

Comment: What commands are you using to drop the user, recreate the user, and create the tables? What user are you connected as when you do this?

Comment: @eaolson - please refer to the edits that I am making now.

Comment: Why does "drop user with cascade" fail ? Isn't that statement supposed to remove or drop the schema and all its objects forever ?

Comment: @stellamatthew, if the DROP USER is failing, what's the error message?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You didn't say what user you were logging in as, but I'll assume it's SYS or someone with pretty much godlike privileges.

In your last line, you are creating table `CARS` *in the current schema*, not in the products schema. What you probably want is:

```
CREATE TABLE products.cars(brand varchar2(25), model varchar2(25));
```

The cars table probably still exists in the current schema from your previous attempt. You can tell if it exists anywhere with this:

```
SELECT owner, object_name, object_type FROM all_objects WHERE object_name = 'CARS';
```

As a side note, it's not really a good idea to grant all privileges to a normal user, but I assume this is for testing procedures. Also, it's preferred to use `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Then, another problem occurred. There were no rows in the table. Again, the fully qualified name of the table solved the problem. 

Thanks once again !

Comment: Btw, why is varchar2 preferred over varchar ?

Comment: It's largely historical. VARCHAR2 is the Oracle datatype for a variable length character string. VARCHAR is currently synonymous with VARCHAR2, but that is not guaranteed in future versions. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/what-is-the-difference-between-oracles-varchar-and-varchar2-datatypes

Answer (score -1):

Your question is way too generic. Based on what I understood, if you use following script, you can drop all objects created by the user -

```
drop user USERNAME cascade;
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A85397_01/statem9d.htm)

And for this to execute successfully you should not have an open connection for this user.

Comment: that does not work. My DB seems to be littered with dead objects that are making my life miserable. This never happens with any other database :( Oracle seems to be weird.